# Left invariant connections on a Lie group

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, connections

The exponential map associated with the (-) - connection on a Lie group is generally not surjective. This is because, for this connection, the one-parameter subgroups and geodesics coincide. If we drop the requirement that one-parameter subgroups are geodesics, is it possible to put a left invariant connection on a Lie group for which the geodesic exponential map is surjective?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  Just take the Levi-Civita connection of any left-invariant Riemannian metric on the Lie group.  The metric is complete, so any two points can be joined by a geodesic (Hopf-Rinow).  Thus, the geodesic exponential map of that connection starting from the identity is surjective.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Robert. One implication of this is that the $(0)$-connection on a non-compact Lie group will generally not be metric.

Comment: True, its holonomy is non-compact, so it is not the Levi-Civita connection of any Riemannian metric.  On the other hand if the group is semi-simple, then the (0)-connection does preserve the bi-invariant *pseudo*-Riemannian metric.